# Dataset and case class with apply function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, case-class

Say I have the following case class, where I define an apply function in its companion object:

```
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: String) 
object MyClass {
  def apply(a: Int, b: String) = {
    if (b == "")
      new MyClass(a, a.toString)
    else
      new MyClass(a, b)
  }
}

println(MyClass(1,"")) //print MyClass(1,1) 
println(MyClass(2,"3")) // print MyClass(2,3)
```

But now say I want to have this behavior with my datasets:

```
val dx: Dataset[MyClass] = Seq((1,"b"))
        .toDF("a", "b")
        .as[MyClass]

dx.show(false)
```

will print, as expected:

```
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |b  |
+---+---+
```

but now if I do:

```
val dx: Dataset[MyClass] = Seq((1,""))
        .toDF("a", "b")
        .as[MyClass]

dx.show(false)
```

I will have:

```
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |   |
+---+---+
```

While I expected:

```
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |1  |
+---+---+
```

Why is that? Can I have somehow the apply function to be "effective"?

Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: Apparently the `as` method bypass the `apply` and calls the constructor directly. I believe you could do this: `Seq((1,"b")).toDF("a", "b").as[(Int, String)].map(MyClass.apply.tupled)` - Can you confirm if this works?

Comment: This worked: Seq((1,"")).toDF("a", "b").map(r => MyClass.apply(r.getInt(0), r.getString(1)))

Comment: If a row-wise `map` is necessary for enabling `apply`, perhaps using a `when/otherwise` transformation to replace the custom `apply` is worth considering.  As a side note, it's baffling why this question warrants downvotes.